# Implementing debug "overlay" info

Tags: cocos2d, psm

This question is actually about GameEngine2D which is part of PSM SDK (for PlayStation Vita development), however as stated in [documentation](https://psm.playstation.net/static/general/all/psm_sdk/2/doc/en/gameengine2d_overview_en.html#about-gameengine2d) it's loosely based on cocos2d library. I hope that my question is generic enough to be answered by other cocos2d users, so that's why [cocos2d](/questions/tagged/cocos2d) tag. Feel free to check my [question on Sony forum](http://community.eu.playstation.com/t5/GameEngine2D/Implementing-debug-info-quot-layer-quot/m-p/22122819).

Basically I'm trying to implement "debug layer" functionality, i.e. if I press, for example, "Triangle" button some debug information (like FPS) would apper "above" current Scene.

Currently I've implemented it this way:

1. I have a `DebugNode : Node` class, that performs necessary drawing,
   it's instance is created on app init, and reference is stored in a
   "global-like" `Game` class.
2. On Trianle press I check `Director.Instance.CurrentScene.Children`, and if does not contain `DebugNode` instance add it, or remove otherwide (so it's a toggle).

It's working fine, but it have issue I don't like, on a scene switch new scene does not have `DebugNode`, and also I need to remove `DebugNode` from `CurrentScene` before scene change, because `Node` can't have multiple parents. The solution to this could be by having multiple `DebugNode` instances, but that is also solution I don't like.

I have 2 questions regarding this:
1. Is my approach to a task is generraly reasonable? Is it done if not the best way, but at least reasonable way?
2. How my approach could be improved, particularly in case of Scene switching?

Comment: I really wish I could help you. I love PSM and even have two games in the store now, but I don't use the `HighLevel` stuff. I hope you can get your question answered.

Comment: @PandaPajama wow, great, did you implemented all basic absractions by yourself (maybe starting with a TutoLib)? Seems pretty tough for me for now, I guess ^_^

Comment: @PandaPajama could you possibly look at other question on PSM I have? http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/82779/refresh-rate-in-psm-apps

Comment: Yes. My games are cross platform, so I have hardware abstractions for all the platforms I support.